# Pipeline.py showing exception

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy, mysql-python

I am building a small project in Scrapy and am new to Scrapy.
When I am running my spider, it shows an exception error in my pipeline which says:

> item['Number'][0], exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

My pipeline file:

```
import sys
from scrapy.utils.python import unicode_to_str
import MySQLdb
from project2.settings import MYSQL


# the Pipeline settings.
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        db=MySQLdb.connect(user='root', passwd='', db='project2', host='127.0.0.1', charset = "utf8", use_unicode = True)
        self.c=db.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            self.c.execute("""INSERT INTO crawlerapp_directory (Catogory, Bussiness_name, Description, Number, Web_url)  
                            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                           (item['Catogory'][0],
                            item['Bussiness_name'][0],
                            item['Description'][0],
                            item['Number'][0],
                            item['Web_url'][0]))

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
            sys.exit (1)

        return item
```

My spider is crawling fine but it's showing the above exception error and also not saving the scraped data into MySQL DB.

Please guide me to solve the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check that a list contains at least one entry before accessing the first element: `value[0] if value`:

```
class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', passwd='',
            db='project2', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = db.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        def Item(field):
            return item.get(field)[0] if item.get(field) else ''

        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO crawlerapp_directory
            (Category, Business_name, Description, Number, Web_url)
            VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', %s, '%s')""", (
                Item('Category'),
                Item('Business_name'),
                Item('Description'),
                Item('Number'),
                Item('Web_url'),
            ))

        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like item['Number'] is empty. Verify that it contains what you want.

Comment: in number i m trying to store the phone numbers of the scraped data

Comment: well as u said it may be empty, i tried to run my spider without the attribute Number,, the spider ran fine,, error freee,, BUT it did not save the rest data which it is scraping.